# Trying to set an OnRelease event on components registered through a configuration file

Tags: wcf, autofac

I'm registering components that require special handling on release (namely, a WCF clients) via a config file.

```
<autofac>
  <components>
    <component 
      type="SomeType" 
      service="ISomeType"/>
  </components>
</autofac>
```

However, via the configuration file, I don't see how I can specify an event.

I've looked at implementing the OnRelease event via a module, but I seem to lack access to some of the innards required to get it working. Mainly, in:

```
registration.Activating += (s, e) =>
    {
        var ra = new ReleaseAction(() => ReleaseWcfClient(e.Instance));
        e.Context.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>().Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(ra);
    };
```

The `ReleaseAction` class is not available outside Autofac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autofac does not support setting up events via XML configuration. You must do that in code.

However, one way you can do this in a more cross-cutting fashion is to create an Autofac module and override the `AttachToComponentRegistration` method. In there, you can test each registration for something (like whether it's a registration for a particular interface) and attach your `Activating` event handler there.

[There is an example of using `AttachToComponentRegistration` on the Autofac wiki](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Log4-Net-Integration) showing how you can use this event to wire up log4net.

Two other notes:

1. You might be interested in using the `UseWcfSafeRelease()` registration extension for WCF client proxies. I don't know what your `ReleaseWcfClient()` method is doing internally, but if the point of it is to handle the possible exceptions from WCF, Autofac has that in `UseWcfSafeRelease()`. [You can read about that on the wiki](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Wcf-Integration).
2. If a component implements `IDisposable` (the way WCF clients do) then Autofac will automatically track it and handle disposal. If you have something specific you want to run when Autofac executes disposal, [you'd want to use `OnRelease` for the registration](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Deterministic-Disposal). If it implements `IDisposable` and you want to set up your own disposal solution, you need to register the component using `ExternallyOwned()` so your component isn't double-disposed.

(I don't know if either of those latter points apply here, but thought I'd raise them since we were in the territory.)

Comment: I ended up using a module to add the OnRelease code to anything that implements ICommunicationObject. The `ReleaseWcfClient` is pretty much the same as the `UseWcfSafeRelease` code, but with a slight different to make it work with our clients.